# Updateconfig Asterisk extensions.conf

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am using Asterisk 13. I am trying to modify extensions.conf using AMI.

The line in extensions.conf I'm trying to modify looks like:

```
Line-000021-000012: exten=_X.,50005,Dial(${dev},20)
```

I'm trying to change the number of these line 20 by 30.
Using telnet to port 5038 I enter the following:

```
action:updateconfig
srcfilename:extensions.conf
dstfilename:extensions.conf
Action-000000: update
Cat-000000: stdexten
Var-000000: exten
Value-000000:>_X.,50005,Dial(${dev},30)
```

This results in:

```
Response: Success
```

This action change the Line-000021-000000, but I need to change the Line-000021-000012. How can I do it? Any suggestions?

PD: When I use "Var-000012" instead of "Var-000000" the request is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
action:updateconfig
srcfilename:extensions.conf
dstfilename:extensions.conf
Action-000000: update
Cat-000000: stdexten
Var-000000: exten
Match-000000: _X.,50005,Dial(${dev},20)
Value-000000:>_X.,50005,Dial(${dev},30)
```

Comment: Even if you found solution, i recommend you consider do NOT modify dialplan using AMI. Use gotoif and func_odbc in dialplan instead. Method  you are using is no scalable and will bring alot of bug&debug issues.